# Can I use multiple certificate for one cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I know you can add multiple domains to one certificate and then assign it to a CloudFront distribution.

But I want my clients can change their domain, so I don't want each time a client requests to change their domain, I have to generate a new certificate for all existing domains (they have to do the validation).

Do I have to create another certificate and another Cloudfront distribution for each client? Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not associate more than one certificate for one CF distribution, see here: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-ssl-certificates-cloudfront/

The best approach is to use a Multi-Domain Certificate from ACM. There you can add up to 100 domains for one certificate, even with wildcards. You can then use this certificate to add all of these domains to your Cloudfront Distribution as Alternate domain names.